# Different vehicle profiles with Graphhopper in Android version

Tags: android, graphhopper

I read that the simplest process that works in using multiple vehicle profiles (car ,foot , hike) is to download an osm/pbf file from
Geofabrik and modify the config properties, in order to produce a graph
with CH off and the vehicles you wish.
Then I can load the produced graph and play with it by using the proper
vehicle.

The thing is that I couldn't understand how I can modify the **config properties** and where?

please any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config.properties files sits in the root of the repository ([see dev guide](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/0.7/docs/core/quickstart-from-source.md)) or at the relative location if you install GraphHopper via the zip file ([see user guide](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/0.7/docs/web/quickstart.md))

Then you need to change the line with the flag_encoders to:

```
graph.flag_encoders=car,foot,hike
```